# Cs:Go Command to always allow GSI allplayers_*

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm writing a program using CS:GO's Game State Integration and I need to receive scoreboard information about the players in my custom game. Their score, for example.

The problem is that CS:GO will only make this data available if the client is a spectator. Is there any way at all that I can enable the sending of this data seeing as I am able to run privileged commands on the server?

My last resort is getting every player to run the program and getting it to collect everything in a central database, but that would be much less convenient for everyone.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question belongs here, as it seems to go into technical aspects of a game... As for the solution, maybe you can attempt to make a program which connects to the game as a spectator, then retrieves the required data?

Comment: Sorry but writing programs is outside the scope of Arqade.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks guys

Comment: Maybe try [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com)